# php error message affecting height of textboxes

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using php to display an error message to the user. The code is sitting at the top of the page and once the error message displays, it affects the height of my textboxes. I coded the height in a style sheet. Also, my error message is sitting inside of a div. I tried using the span tag but that isn't working either since its still sitting at the top line of the page. This is the error message in php:

```
if($result != "")
{
        echo "<div id='Error'>"; 
        echo "<b>The following errors occured:</b><br>";
        echo $result;
        echo "</div>";
}
```

Registration div css:

```
#RegBody
{
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url(LilyPads.jpg);
    height: 82.7vh;
}

#RegContents
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 39px auto 0 402px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 455px;
    padding-left: 57px;
}

#RegisterUser
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-left: 112px;
    color: #1A3D5B;
    width: 215px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1A3D5B;
    border-color: #1A3D5B;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Error message css:

```
#Error
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 147px 0 0 70px;
    color: red;
}
```

Here's the css for the textboxes:

```
input[type='text']
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-indent: 10px;
    width: 210px;
    height: 25px;
    border-color: #1A3D5B;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Before the error message:

[image: Before error message]

I was thinking that maybe its the font size that's the issue but regardless...a white line also appears at the bottom of the page:

[image: Error]

Please have patience with me. I'm a student and new to php. Thank you

Comment: We need to see the CSS to see what is the problem.

Comment: @Markus Zeller I've edited my question. Would it help to include images of the issue?

Comment: @NJH can you please share an image before and after error.

Comment: @Hakik Zaman it's been updated

Comment: What is the CSS of the error box? Still too less debugging information.

Comment: @Markus Zeller Done. I've added the Registration div as well

Comment: I don't see any error in what you've posted so far. So I think, there must be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can tell you how to rectify the error (though i am still looking for the reason because of which it happens).
what i did is that i inserted the php code inside body tag and it work fine no change in Textbox dimensions.Below is the code i wrote  to prove the same

```
    <?php 
$result=1;
 echo "<div id='Error'>"; 
        echo "<b>The following errors occured:</b><span>";
        echo $result;
        echo "</span></div>";
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    

         input[type='text']
   {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-indent: 10px;
    width: 210px;
    height:25px;
   
    border-color: #1A3D5B;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
   }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>

<input type='text' name=''>
    
 
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: This worked. I believe the php code at the top overrode the css and set a few things to default or just simply took up the space the textboxes where sitting in

Comment: @NJH maybe but that should not affect the text box ,i simply added some padding to the textbox and that would not change the dimensions on error message,just a shotgap to solve these issues